# Action Bar problems

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an Action Bar with only the view title and one item. I have applied the `withText` attribute to it because I would like Android to show the item title. However, it won't display the title text. There's plenty of space for it to display.

Secondly, I would like to know whether it is possible to change the view title in the actionbar on for example a button click, or not.

Comment: When you refer to the item title I'm assuming you are talking about the menu items. Even there might be enough space, the OS decides whether to show or not the text. If you want text and menu item shown at all times you will need to create a custom view and inflate this as a menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have set your `MenuItem` to have the `showAsAction="withText"` option, it is ultimately up to the system to determine whether or not to show the text.  `withText` is merely a hint to the system that you would like the text to be shown.  On most phones (e.g. Galaxy Nexus), the text is always hidden in portrait mode and shown if there is room in landscape mode.

As for setting the `ActionBar` title, you can do so by calling `setTitle`.  Doing this on a `Button` click could look something like this:

```
Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setTitle("New Title");
    }
});
```